# enable up one folder in hierarchy

Tags: php, apache

I'm using Apache 2.4.7 and PHP 5.5.10

My folder tree is:

```
C:\Apache24\htdocs\
    --> lib-company
        --> styles
            --> xxx.css
        --> js
            --> xxx.js
    --> site
        --> index.php
```

At file "httpd.conf" I set DocumentRoot to "c:/Apache24/htdocs/site" so
when I type "localhost" at the browser "index.php" is executed.

At my "index.php" I've:

```
<!-- styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../lib-company/styles/xxx.css"/>

<!-- scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib-company/js/xxx.js"></script>
```

The problem is: I receive error '404 (Not Found) at both of the files

```
GET http://localhost/lib-company/styles/xxx.css 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost/lib-company/js/xxx.js 404 (Not Found)
```

I'm looking for how to allow go up in the hierarchy without change the site structure.

Comment: Open up your hieracrchy is very dangerous if you don't know exactly what you're doing. Is it realy that important to keep file structure?

Comment: Please suggest the correct way to fix the problem.

Comment: I would change the dirictory structure so that they would reside inside site dir instead. But I don't know if thats even a solution in your case!